# WebView unable to download media from wordpress websites(POST)

Tags: java, android, audio, webview, android-download-manager

I am unable to download media files, either audio or video through the WebView.I have been trying to figure this out for more than three days I have read as much threats relating to this issue on the internet but i don't seem to find out a solution to it.I would really appreciate if someone can help me out. This would mean a lot to me.

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ViewAnimator.ViewAnimatorListener {
private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;
private List<SlideMenuItem> list = new ArrayList<>();
private ContentFragment contentFragment;
private ViewAnimator viewAnimator;
private LinearLayout linearLayout;





@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    contentFragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(R.drawable.content_music);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, contentFragment)
            .commit();
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.setScrimColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);
    linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        }
    });


    setActionBar();
    createMenuList();
    viewAnimator = new ViewAnimator<>(this, list, contentFragment, drawerLayout, this);
}


private void setActionBar() {
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    drawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            drawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            toolbar,  /* nav drawer icon to replace 'Up' caret */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description */
    ) {

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            linearLayout.removeAllViews();
            linearLayout.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
            if (slideOffset > 0.6 && linearLayout.getChildCount() == 0)
                viewAnimator.showMenuContent();
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };
    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerToggle);
}

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    drawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager =
            (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView =
            (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(
            searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
protected boolean onPrepareOptionsPanel(View view, Menu menu) {
    if (menu != null) {
        if (menu.getClass().getSimpleName().equals("MenuBuilder")) {
            try {
                Method m = menu.getClass().getDeclaredMethod(
                        "setOptionalIconsVisible", Boolean.TYPE);
                m.setAccessible(true);
                m.invoke(menu, true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                        "onMenuOpened...unable to set icons for overflow menu",
                        e);
            }
        }
    }
    return super.onPrepareOptionsPanel(view, menu);
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.profile) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutUsActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(id==R.id.Logout){
        Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(id==R.id.Settings) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
    if(id==R.id.About_bridgeGap){
            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutUsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    }
    return true;
}



@Override
public ScreenShotable onSwitch(Resourceble resourceble, ScreenShotable screenShotable, int position) {

    int primaryColorCanvas = R.color.colorPrimary;

    switch (resourceble.getName()) {
        case ContentFragment.CLOSE:
            return screenShotable;

        case ContentFragment.HOME:
            ContentFragment fragment = ContentFragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment)
                    .addToBackStack("Home").commit();
            return replaceFragment(fragment, position);

        case Artists_Fragment.ARTISTS:
            Artists_Fragment fragment2 = Artists_Fragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment2)
                    .addToBackStack("Artists").commit();
            return replaceFragment(fragment2, position);


        case AudioFragment.AUDIO:
            AudioFragment fragment3 = AudioFragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment3)
                    .addToBackStack("Audio").commit();
            return replaceFragment(fragment3, position);

        case VideoFragment.VIDEO:
            VideoFragment fragment4 = VideoFragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment4)
                    .addToBackStack("Video").commit();
            return replaceFragment(fragment4, position);
        case InterviewsFragment.INTERVIEWS:
            InterviewsFragment fragment5 = InterviewsFragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment5)
                    .addToBackStack("Interviews").commit();
            return replaceFragment(fragment5, position);
        case BlogFragment.BLOG:
            BlogFragment fragment6 = BlogFragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment6)
                    .addToBackStack("Blog").commit();
            return replaceFragment(fragment6, position);
        case ContactFragment.CONTACT:
            ContactFragment fragment7 = ContactFragment.newInstance(primaryColorCanvas);
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,fragment7)
                    .addToBackStack("Contact").commit();
        default:
            return replaceFragment(screenShotable, position);
    }
}

private ScreenShotable replaceFragment(ScreenShotable screenShotable, int position) {
    View view = findViewById(R.id.content_frame);
    int finalRadius = Math.max(view.getWidth(), view.getHeight());
    SupportAnimator animator = ViewAnimationUtils.createCircularReveal(view, 0, position, 0, finalRadius);
    animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
    animator.setDuration(ViewAnimator.CIRCULAR_REVEAL_ANIMATION_DURATION);
    findViewById(R.id.content_overlay).setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), screenShotable.getBitmap()));
    animator.start();
    return screenShotable;
}

private void createMenuList() {
    SlideMenuItem menuItem0 = new SlideMenuItem(contentFragment.CLOSE, R.drawable.icn_close);
    list.add(menuItem0);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem1 = new SlideMenuItem(contentFragment.HOME, R.drawable.home);
    list.add(menuItem1);
    SlideMenuItem menuIte2 = new SlideMenuItem(Artists_Fragment.ARTISTS, R.drawable.singer);
    list.add(menuIte2);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem3 = new SlideMenuItem(AudioFragment.AUDIO, R.drawable.music);
    list.add(menuItem3);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem4 = new SlideMenuItem(VideoFragment.VIDEO, R.drawable.video);
    list.add(menuItem4);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem5 = new SlideMenuItem(InterviewsFragment.INTERVIEWS, R.drawable.interviews);
    list.add(menuItem5);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem6 = new SlideMenuItem(BlogFragment.BLOG, R.drawable.blogblue);
    list.add(menuItem6);
    SlideMenuItem menuItem7 = new SlideMenuItem(ContactFragment.CONTACT, R.drawable.contact_us_logos);
    list.add(menuItem7);




}


@Override
public void disableHomeButton() {
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void enableHomeButton() {
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawers();

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    int count = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();

    if (count == 0) {
        super.onBackPressed();
        //additional code
    } else {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    }

}

@Override
public void addViewToContainer(View view) {
    linearLayout.addView(view);
}
```

}

Artists_Fragment.java

```
    public class Artists_Fragment extends Fragment implements ScreenShotable {

private View containerView;
private WebView mwebView;
protected int res;
private Bitmap bitmap;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
public static final String ARTISTS = "Artists";
public static Artists_Fragment newInstance(int resId) {

    Artists_Fragment contentFragment = new Artists_Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(Integer.class.getName(), resId);
    contentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return contentFragment;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.container);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    res = getArguments().getInt(Integer.class.getName());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artists, container, false);
    mwebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mwebView.loadUrl("http://xclusiveinterviews.com/artists/");
    WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
    mwebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("BridgeGap");
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


    /** Handle back press for WebView **/
    mwebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if((i==keyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)&&mwebView.canGoBack());
                mwebView.goBack();
                return true;

            }

    });


  mwebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); //Notify client once download is completed!
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "Name of your downloadble file goes here, example: Mathematics II ");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File", //To notify the Client that the file is being downloaded
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });

    return rootView;
}

private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if (url.contains("xclusiveinterviews.com")) {
            view.loadUrl(url);

        } else {
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(i);

        }


        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ErrorActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}

private class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

}


@Override
public void takeScreenShot() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(containerView.getWidth(),
                    containerView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            containerView.draw(canvas);
            Artists_Fragment.this.bitmap = bitmap;
        }
    };

    thread.start();

}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

logcat

```
    07-11 16:44:02.135 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap    
    D/WebViewCallback: onProgressChanged=0
    07-11 16:44:02.137 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap                        
   D/WebViewCallback: onPageStart, url = http://xclusiveinterviews.com   
   /wp-admin/admin-post.php
    07-11 16:44:02.137 6393-6456/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap    
    D/WebViewCallback:  
    shouldInterceptRequest=http://xclusiveinterviews.com/wp-admin/admin-   
    post.php
    07-11 16:44:02.144 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap   
    D/WebViewCallback: onLoadResource=http://xclusiveinterviews.com/wp-
    admin/admin-post.php 
    07-11 16:44:02.144 6393-6489/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap D/libc-   
    netbsd: getaddrinfo: xclusiveinterviews.com get result from proxy >>
   07-11 16:44:02.169 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap  
   D/AwContents: setContentsSize 324, 1059
   07-11 16:44:02.170 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap   
   D/AwContents: setPageScaleFactor 1.0
   07-11 16:44:04.680 6393-6456/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap W/chromium:   
  [WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(66)] http://xclusiveinterviews.com/wp-
  admin/admin-post.php#-3#1
  07-11 16:44:04.685 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap  
  D/WebViewCallback: onProgressChanged=100
  07-11 16:44:04.702 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap   
  D/WebViewCallback: onPageFinished, url = http://xclusiveinterviews.com
  /product/breathe-in-a-new-life/
    07-11 16:44:02.135 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap   
   D/WebViewCallback: onProgressChanged=0
  07-11 16:44:02.137 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap 
  D/WebViewCallback: onPageStart, url = http://xclusiveinterviews.com/wp- 
  admin/admin-post.php
  07-11 16:44:02.137 6393-6456/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap  
  D/WebViewCallback: shouldInterceptRequest=http://xclusiveinterviews.com  
  /wp-admin/admin-post.php
  07-11 16:44:02.144 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap  
  D/WebViewCallback: onLoadResource=http://xclusiveinterviews.com/wp- 
  admin/admin-post.php
  07-11 16:44:02.144 6393-6489/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap D/libc-
 netbsd: getaddrinfo: xclusiveinterviews.com get result from proxy >>    
  07-11 16:44:02.169 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap     
 D/AwContents: setContentsSize 324, 1059
 07-11 16:44:02.170 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap D/AwContents:  
 setPageScaleFactor 1.0
07-11 16:44:04.680 6393-6456/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap W/chromium:   
 [WARNING:aw_network_delegate.cc(66)] http://xclusiveinterviews.com/wp- 
admin/admin-post.php#-3#1
07-11 16:44:04.685 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap   
D/WebViewCallback: onProgressChanged=100
 07-11 16:44:04.702 6393-6393/com.bridgegap.akang.bridgegap  
D/WebViewCallback: onPageFinished, url = http://xclusiveinterviews.com  
/product/breathe-in-a-new-life/
```

Comment: I did a work around and finally solved it. Android shouldOverrideUrlLoading doesnt support POST method so my download link wasn't working.What i did was edit my .httaccess in my webserver to allow download through links. And change the code a bit.

Answer (score 0):

public class Artists_Fragment extends Fragment implements ScreenShotable {

```
private View containerView;
private WebView mwebView;
protected int res;
private Bitmap bitmap;
public ProgressBar progressBar;
public static final String ARTISTS = "Artists";

public static Artists_Fragment newInstance(int resId) {

    Artists_Fragment contentFragment = new Artists_Fragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(Integer.class.getName(), resId);
    contentFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    return contentFragment;
}


@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    this.containerView = view.findViewById(R.id.container);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    res = getArguments().getInt(Integer.class.getName());
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_artists, container, false);
    mwebView = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mwebView.loadUrl("http://xclusiveinterviews.com/artists/");
    WebSettings webSettings = mwebView.getSettings();
    mwebView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("BridgeGap");
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mwebView.setWebViewClient(new myWebViewClient());
    mwebView.setWebChromeClient(new myWebChromeClient());
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.progressbar);


    /** Handle back press for WebView **/
    mwebView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if ((i == keyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mwebView.canGoBack()) ;
            mwebView.goBack();
            return true;

        }

    });

    mwebView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimeType,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));
            request.setMimeType(mimeType);
            String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
            request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
            request.setDescription("Downloading file...");
            request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition,
                    mimeType));
            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(
                    Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(
                            url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Downloading File",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
    return rootView;
}

private class myWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url.contains("xclusiveinterviews.com")) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
    } else {
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);

    }


    return false;

}
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
  }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, errorCode, description, failingUrl);

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ErrorActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

}

```
private class myWebChromeClient extends WebChromeClient{

}


@Override
public void takeScreenShot() {
    Thread thread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(containerView.getWidth(),
                    containerView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            containerView.draw(canvas);
            Artists_Fragment.this.bitmap = bitmap;
        }
    };

    thread.start();

}

@Override
public Bitmap getBitmap() {
    return bitmap;
}
```

}